# Samba configuaration not working

Tags: linux, windows, samba, centos6, share

I am trying to set up a Samba share with a Windows computer from CentOS6. This is my current samba config:

```
[global]
restrict anonymous = no
domain master = no
preferred master = no
workgroup = workgroup
ldap ssl = no
server signing = auto
wins support = no

[test]
path = /home/test
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok =  no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

I can access the directory specified on my Windows computer, but access is denied if I try to create a folder or save a file into it. I have tried this config with many different folders (not just /home/test) with them all having the same result. The directories all belong to the same user that I log into as on the Windows computer and that user also has full privileges of the directory recursively (chmod and chown have been used at times), and so I don't understand why the access is denied.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `security = user` to your `[global]` section. What file system are you using (eg Ext4)?

Comment: Side note: Setting masks to 0777 is a security risk, everything written to the server becomes executable. The directory mask should be 0755 or 0775, and the create mask should be 0644 or 0664.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the addition specified in your first comment, but that did not work. I do realize the risk, but I changed them to that in an effort just to get a working system; I will rectify this before I put it into production. The system I am using is Ext4.

Answer (score -1):

execute this

```
chmod 777 /home/test
```

And change your section test in samba config for this:

```
[test]
path = /home/test
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
security = share
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have already tried that and it doesn't work as, even though the directory can be accessed from windows, directories and files cannot be created within it.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but that still did not solve the issue.

Comment: I added security param and I tested in my environment and it worked.

Comment: What is security param?

Comment: parameter security = share. I typed wrong my another comment.
you can read more about security = share in [samba doc parameter security](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html)